# Displaying not the id, but the name of a certain data from a table connected with foreign key. - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to pass data to my view and i want to visualize the name of some records not the id so in my controller I have this:

```
`public function getIndex() {

        return view('admin.rules.list', [
            'rules' => ClassSubject::get(),
            'classes'=> Clas::lists('name', 'id'),
            'subjects' => Subject::lists('name', 'id'),
            'teachers'=>User::where('type','=','teacher')->get()->lists('full_name','id')
        ]);


    }

    public function postIndex(Request $request) {
        $rule = ClassSubject::create([
            'class_id'=> $request->get('class_id'),
            'subject_id'=> $request->get('subject_id'),
            'teacher_id'=> $request->get('teacher_id'),
        ]);

        if($rule->id) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
                'type'=> 'success',
                'message' => 'Успешно записан нов клас!'

            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
            'type'=> 'danger',
            'message' => 'Класът не е записан!'
        ]);
    }`
```

I'm passing it in my view like this (part of the table):

```
`@foreach($rules as $rule)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $rule->user->full_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $rule->subject->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $rule->clas->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $rule->created_at->format('d.m.Y, H:i') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $rule->updated_at->format('d.m.Y, H:i') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ url('admin/rule/edit/'.$rule->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Редактирай</a>
                            <a href="{{ url('admin/rule/delete/'.$rule->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Изтрий</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach`
```

So this thing: `<td>{{ $rule->subject->name}}</td>` works perfectly and I see the name of the subject, not the id, but with the other two: `<td>{{ $rule->user->full_name }}</td>` and `<td>{{ $rule->clas->name}}</td>`

I have this error msg:

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\school_system\resources\views\admin\rules\list.blade.php)**

I'm posting the connection of the tables (models), because I think that may have smthg in common:

User class:

```
`public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function classes() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Clas::class);
    }

    public function subjects() {
        return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
    }

    public function classSubject() {
        return $this->hasMany(ClassSubject::class);
    }

    public function studentMark() {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentMark::class);
    }

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }

}`
```

Clas class:

```
`protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'profile_id'

    ];

    protected $table = 'classes';

    public function profile() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function classSubject() {
        return $this->hasMany(ClassSubject::class);
    }

    public function student() {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function studentMark() {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentMark::class);
    }`
```

Subject class:

```
`protected $fillable = [
             'name'
    ];

    public function classSubject() {
        return $this->hasMany(ClassSubject::class);
    }

    public function studentMark() {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentMark::class);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function teacher() {
        return $this->hasMany(Teacher::class);
    }`
```

And the table that connecting them:

```
`class ClassSubject extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'class_id',
            'subject_id',
            'teacher_id',
            'method_of_study_id',

        ];

        public function subject()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
        }

        public function classes()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Clas::class);
        }

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }


    }`
```

I would be really thankfull if someone can help, i'm trying to fix this for days.. :)

Answer (score 0):

the first problem I can see is:

```
$rule->clas->name
```

there is no clas method on ClassSubject. It should be:

```
$rule->classes->name
```

or you can rename the method, as it is not conventional to have a plural name for a "belongsTo" relationship method

Comment: yes, but even with `$rule->classes->name` doesn't work, still the same error

Comment: how many results are you getting for 'ClassSubject::get()' ? If it's only one eloquent will return a model rather than a collection. The model would not be iterable and would throw an error if given as the argument to a foreach loop

Comment: No, its not only one. The problem is with these two:`<td>{{ $rule->user->full_name }}</td>` ; `<td>{{ $rule->clas->name}}</td>` because if I call them like this: `<td>{{ $rule->teacher_id }}</td>` and `<td>{{ $rule->class_id}}</td>` my page is displayed but I see only the IDs ...